# Checkbox is not able to disable after adding Hidden type

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, jstl

I have three check boxes (checkbox1 , 2 and 3) . I want to disable 'check box 3' when I click on check box 1 and Enable check box 3 when click check box2. This is working fine, but after adding hidden field for check box 3, the disabling is not working.Please see my code below. Could anyone please help me ?

```
<html>
<script> 
 function callFun1()
 { 
   document.getElementById('three').disabled=true; 
 }   
 function callFun2()
 { 
   document.getElementById('three').disabled=false; 
 }
</script>
  <head>     
    <body>             
      <table border="2" align="center">     
         <tr><td>CheckBox 1  <input type="checkbox" name="one" id="one" value="true" onClick="callFun1()"></td></tr>         
         <tr><td>CheckBox 2  <input type="checkbox" name="two" id="two" value="true" onClick="callFun2()"></td></tr>     
         <tr><td> CheckBox 3 <input type="hidden" name="three" id="three" value=""/>
                             <input type="checkbox" name="three" id="three" value="true" /> </td> </tr>     
      </table>        
    </body> 
  </head>  
</html>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have added a field with the same id and `document.getElementById('three')` only returns the first field because id should be unique

Answer (score 1):

You've got duplicate ids.  IDs should be unique on the whole page.  Change the id of one of your inputs to be something different and it should solve your problem.

Depending on the browser the getElementById method will usually return the first element in the DOM with that ID. In this case you are probably disabling the hidden input, rather than the checkbox as you require.

You could avoid having the hidden input entirely in this case by just making the checkbox readonly (after un-checking it) by using the following code.

```
function callFun1()
 { 
   document.getElementById('three').readonly=false; 
 }
function callFun2()
 { 
   document.getElementById('three').check=false; 
   document.getElementById('three').readonly=true; 
 }
```